# Casting a Geography type in PostGIS

Tags: postgis, postgresql, database

I have the following table defined, which uses PostGIS geography.

```
CREATE TABLE test_geog (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    boundary GEOGRAPHY(Polygon)
);
```

I added the following test polygon to the table:

```
INSERT INTO test_geog VALUES (ST_GeographyFromText('SRID=4326;POLYGON((0 0, 0 5, 5 5, 5 0, 0 0))'));
```

I am trying to determine whether a point lies within any of the polygons in this table.  I have this query:

```
SELECT ST_ContainsProperly(ST_GeographyFromText('Point(2 2)'), area)
FROM (SELECT boundary FROM test_geog) AS area;
```

This yields the following error:

```
ERROR:  function st_containsproperly(geography, record) does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT ST_ContainsProperly(ST_GeographyFromText('Point(2 2)'...
            ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

How do I convert this "record" into a `POLYGON`?  I'm confused because it seems like the column has already been declared to only hold `POLYGON` types, but for some reason that is not what I am pulling out of the database.

I attempted to cast the record to a `POLYGON` like this:

```
SELECT ST_ContainsProperly(ST_GeographyFromText('Point(2 2)'), CAST (nitf_area AS POLYGON))
FROM (SELECT boundary FROM source_imagery) AS nitf_area;
```

But that gives me this error:

```
ERROR:  cannot cast type record to polygon
LINE 1: ...tainsProperly(ST_GeographyFromText('Point(2 2)'), CAST (nitf...
```

What am I not understanding here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you need the sub-select? And I think ST_ContainsProperly only works with Geometry, not Geography.

```
SELECT ST_ContainsProperly(
          Geometry(ST_GeographyFromText('Point(2 2)')), 
          Geometry(boundary)
       )
FROM test_geog;
```

Comment: Ah, yes you are right about all of that.  ST_ContainsProperly only works for Geometry, so I switched to using ST_Covers instead, which does what I want.  I wanted to avoid casting to Geometry if it's not necessary.  Here is the code I ended up with that works: `SELECT ST_Covers(boundary, ST_GeographyFromText('Point(2 2)'))
FROM source_imagery`